# Why does (?:\s)\w{2}(?:\s) not match only a 2 letter sub string with spaces around it not the spaces as well?

Tags: regex, nano

I am trying to make a regex that matches all sub strings under or equal to 2 characters with a space on ether side. What did I do wrong?

ex what I want to do is have it match `%2` or `q` but not `123` and not the spaces.

update this `\b\w{2}\b` if it also matched one letter sub strings and did not ignore special characters like - or #.

Comment: Do you mean 1-letter words? Like [`\b\w\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gD2kK4/1)? Could you please clarify with 1 or 2 examples? Have a look at the example of [what your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/gD2kK4/2).

Comment: @stribizhev no mean one and two letter words but more importantly I can't get it not to match the spaces while using them to id that it is a sub string.

Comment: What is your regex flavor? Tool/programming language?

Comment: Please understand that matching and capturing are to different things. This matches `a space, two letters and a space`. You've set it to **not capture** the spaces, but in fact, you aren't capturing anything. You could do the matching part with *lookaround* if your regex flavor supports that.

Comment: oh ok thanks I did not know that.

Comment: I do not think nano supports look-behinds, or try `(?<=\s)\w{1,2}(?=\s)` to match 1 or 2 letter words with (white)spaces around.

Comment: no luck it is invalid I can just run `\b\w{2}\b` and `\b\w{1}\b`. thanks

Comment: try this - (\b\w{2})|(\w{2}\b)

Comment: @stribizhev I just tried it on the file not tester and `\b\w{2}\b` it matches sub strings that look like this `-su#` and does not capture `#f` how can that be fixed? also `(\b\w{2})|(\w{2}\b)` gets stuff in longer sub strings.

Comment: I am not getting what you need. Maybe `\b\w{1,2}\b`? Whole 1 or 2 word words?

Comment: @stribizhev So I need to match `1b`, `-b` or `%` but not `-bu` or `abc`. any thing under 3 characters must be matched.

Comment: Without a look-behind - [`(^|\s)\S{1,2}(?=\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/xP0kZ4/1) - and if you replace, restore the captured part with $1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
(^|\s)\S{1,2}(?=\s)
```

Since you cannot use a look-behind, you can use a capture group and if you replace text, you can then restore the captured part with `$1`.

See [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/xP0kZ4/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `(^|\s)` - Group 1 - either a start of string or a whitespace
- `\S{1,2}` - 1 or 2 non-whitespace characters
- `(?=\s)` - check if after 1 or 2 non-whitespace characters we have a whitespace. If not, fail.